# Is this estimation correct for a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis

From the limit development of the function $e^{x}$ we get that
$$
p_{n}(x)≤e^{x}  (1)
$$
for all $x≥0$ where $p_{n}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree n.
Based on inequality (1) I write that
$(x+2)^{m}≤m!2^{m}e^{x}$  (2).
Is  the inequality (2) true for all $x≥0$ and $m∈ℕ$?

Answer (score 1):

In Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ we have
$$
e^x = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ... + \frac{x^m}{m!} + ... 
$$
On the other hand, by the means of Newton expansion the left-side of the inequality could be written as
$$
(x+2)^m = \sum_{k=0}^m {m \choose k} x^k 2^{m-k} \leq 2^m m!  (1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ... + \frac{x^m}{m!})
$$

$$
(x+2)^m \leq 2^m m! (e^x - \frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!} - \frac{x^{m+2}}{(m+2)!} - \frac{x^{m+3}}{(m+3)!} - ...)
$$

$$
(x+2)^m + 2^m m!(\frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!} + \frac{x^{m+2}}{(m+2)!} + \frac{x^{m+3}}{(m+3)!}  + ...) \leq 2^m m!(e^x)
$$
It could be concluded no matter how big the $m$ is, as the polynomial degree of exponential function is infinite, it is always true.

Code For intution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.arange(1,5)
for m in np.arange(1,5):
    plt.subplot(2,2,m)
    y1 = (x+2)**m
    y2 = 2**m*np.math.factorial(m)*np.exp(x)
    plt.plot(x,y1)
    plt.plot(x,y2)
    plt.title('m = {}'.format(m))
    plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]